# Building a stream in python 2.7: how to get stream.read() to work

Tags: python, python-2.7

I needed to construct a stream around an iterator of strings (concatenating the strings, essentially).

So I wrote:

```
class _Whatever(io.RawIOBase):
```

and then filled in `__init__`, `__enter__`, `__exit__`, and `read(self, size)`.

Basic tests passed. Then, in a more serious application, something called `fp.read()` on my object, and that was not defined. Did I pick the wrong base class? Do I need to just fill in all these boilerplate methods for myself?

To be clearer, my read method was:

```
 def read(self, size):
    # do whatever
```

so 'size' was a mandatory parameter. Based on comments here, I changed it to say `size=-1` and delegate to `readall` in this case, and that seems to have cured the problem.

Comment: [_Read up to n bytes from the object and return them. As a convenience, if n is unspecified or -1, readall() is called. Otherwise, only one system call is ever made. Fewer than n bytes may be returned if the operating system call returns fewer than n bytes._](https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#io.RawIOBase.read)

Comment: I think you are telling me that I mis-coded 'read', making the second arg mandatory when I should have made it optional?

Comment: ```...was not defined...``` - Are you saying that it threw an AttributeError?

Comment: @wwil I don't have it in front of me, but it worked to change the definition of read to `read(self, size=-1)` and add an if statement to call `readall`, as hinted by @ Łukasz Rogalski.

Comment: @bmargulies no, I told that actual AttributeError likely comes from lack of `readall`, not lack of `read`. Always include full traceback and [MCVE].

Comment: Well, that's interesting. The error message most definitely complained that 'read requires an argument', not 'you're missing readall', and changing read to not require an argument (and call readall) worked. Next time I'll paste more. In the mean time, i think you should make an answer and take credit for solving my problem.